# 暗号化技術の重ねがけが逆効果になるケースは無いか？

Tags: security, ssl

TLSで暗号化された通信経路上を流すデータに対して、アプレイケーションのレイヤで更に暗号化を独自にかける場合、それによってかえって保護のレベルがTLS単体よりも低下する可能性はありますか？
それとも、少なくともTLSによる保護のレベルまでは保証されますか？

もしTLS単体よりも低下する場合、例えばどのような理由により起こり得るでしょうか？

「SSL/TLSだけだとよく脆弱性問題も起きてて心配だから、自分たちでも暗号化してセキュリティを高めよう」という話が身近にあったのですが、セキュリティ素人のアレンジが本当に有効なのかどうか気になっています。
車輪の再発明程度の問題で済むならまだしも、逆効果になってしまっては大変なので・・・

Answer (score 7, accepted):

たとえば暗号に対する中間一致攻撃と言うのがあります。

平文→(1段目の暗号化)→1段目の暗号文→(2段目の暗号化)→暗号文、暗号文→(2段目の暗号化の復号)→1段目の暗号分→(1段目の暗号化の復号)→平文、という処理をしてるとして、暗号と復号のプロセスから

- 平文→(1段目の暗号化)→1段目の暗号文
- 暗号文→(2段目の暗号化の復号)→1段目の暗号文

を取り出します。これを全てのパターンの鍵で試行して、「1段目の暗号文」が一致すればその鍵が正解です。素直に全件探索すると「1段目の試行×2段目の試行」の回数がいるところ、「1段目+2段目」の回数で済むことになります。

ともに128bit鍵だとすると、256bit分の強度になるかと思いきや129bit分にしかならない、と言う話です。

また、暗号の強度はアルゴリズムそのものだけではなく運用にも関わります。

1段目の暗号の運用をきちんと考えないと、2段目が破られたら結局1段目も破られるので意味なし、ということが考えられます。(極端な例を出すと、1段目の鍵をTLSのみで暗号化して送っているとか)

ということで「セキュリティを強化したつもりが全然意味なかった」ということは容易に発生しうることになります。

ここからは自信が無いのですが、1段目を加えたせいで2段目(TLS)の強度が落ちるようなことがあるかというと、1段目でヘッダなどとして構造化データを付加するとその部分が既知となり攻撃の助けになる、と言う可能性はあるかと思います。とはいっても、普通にTLSを使っていても上位レイヤのヘッダや構造化されたデータはあるので、増えると言っても微々たる物ではないでしょうか。

なんにせよ、本当にこういうことを必要とされているのであれば、専門家に支援してもらうほうが良いです。

Comment: 中間一致攻撃への対策例が、3DES ですね。なぜ 2DES ではいけなかったのか。

Answer (score 3):

ネットワークプロトコルスタックと言う言葉があります。ネットワーク的に下の層をそっくり入れ替えても、ネットワーク的に上の層はそのまま動かすことができる、といった意味ですね。

TLS はトランスポート層とアプリケーション層の中間に当たるレイヤにいます。一方で我々、一般的開発者が作るのはアプリケーション層です。 TLS はアプリケーションが平文を転送しようが暗号文を転送しようが気にしませんから、その意味で暗号ロジックは独立していると考えてよいでしょう。なので「故意に TLS を阻害する」ようなことをしない限り保護レベルが低下することは無いとオイラは考えます。
＃証明書が不完全です、の警告を無視して継続させるような運用をするとか・・・

効果があるかは別問題ってことで。攻撃者がいるとして、
- セキュリティ専門家の考えた暗号を解くのに１００００の手間がかかるとして、
- セキュリティ素人の考えた暗号を解くには１の手間しかかからない、
かもしれません。逆に
- 広く使われているセキュリティプロトコルの脆弱性が見つかったら多くの攻撃者が興味を持ち
 誰でも簡単に使える攻撃手法が広く公開されるかもしれない
- １アプリケーションが使っているオレオレ暗号に興味を持つ攻撃者は少ないかもしれない
なんてこともありそうです。

素人流オレオレ暗号を開発コストかけて実装して、どの程度役に立つかは要検討ですね。
最終的には営業的、戦略的判断とかそういうことになりそう。

Answer (score 2):

例えば暗号文を復号するための情報として、固定のヘッダ、あるいは容易に予測できる内容のヘッダを儲けてしまったとする。その固定のヘッダのおかげで既知平文攻撃が可能になるって事はあるかもしれない。